# Ошибка сборки ffmpeg с поддержкой opencv

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, rpm

Fedora 23. Пакет opencv(3.1.0-8) собран из официального src.rpm, ставится корректно.
При попытке сборки ffpeg(2.8.10-2) тоже из офиц репозитория при конфигурировании получаю:

```
    $ ./configure --enable-libopencv
    ERROR: opencv not found using pkg-config


    $ cat /usr/lib64/pkgconfig/opencv.pc
    # Package Information for pkg-config

    prefix=/usr
    exec_prefix=${prefix}
    libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib64
    includedir_old=${prefix}/include/opencv
    includedir_new=${prefix}/include

    Name: OpenCV
    Description: Open Source Computer Vision Library
    Version: 3.1.0
    Libs: -L${exec_prefix}/lib64 -lopencv_shape -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_aruco -lopencv_bgsegm -lopencv_bioinspired -lopencv_ccalib -lopencv_cvv -lopencv_dnn -lopencv_dpm -lopencv_fuzzy -lopencv_hdf -lopencv_line_descriptor -lopencv_optflow -lopencv_plot -lopencv_reg -lopencv_saliency -lopencv_stereo -lopencv_structured_light -lopencv_rgbd -lopencv_surface_matching -lopencv_tracking -lopencv_datasets -lopencv_text -lopencv_face -lopencv_video -lopencv_ximgproc -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_xobjdetect -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_ml -lopencv_xphoto -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_photo -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core
    Libs.private: -L/usr/lib64 -lQt5Test -lQt5Concurrent -lQt5OpenGL -L/lib64 -lwebp -lpng -ltiff -ljasper -ljpeg -lImath -lIlmImf -lIex -lHalf -lIlmThread -lgdal -lgstvideo-1.0 -lgstapp-1.0 -lgstbase-1.0 -lgstriff-1.0 -lgstpbutils-1.0 -lgstreamer-1.0 -lucil -lunicap -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lfontconfig -lfreetype -lglib-2.0 -ldc1394 -lv4l1 -lv4l2 -lgphoto2 -lgphoto2_port -lexif -lQt5Core -lQt5Gui -lQt5Widgets -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lz -ldl -lm -ltesseract -llept -lpthread -lrt -lGLU -lGL
    Cflags: -I${includedir_old} -I${includedir_new}


    $ pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv
    -I/usr/include/opencv -lopencv_shape -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_aruco -lopencv_bgsegm -lopencv_bioinspired -lopencv_ccalib -lopencv_cvv -lopencv_dnn -lopencv_dpm -lopencv_fuzzy -lopencv_hdf -lopencv_line_descriptor -lopencv_optflow -lopencv_plot -lopencv_reg -lopencv_saliency -lopencv_stereo -lopencv_structured_light -lopencv_rgbd -lopencv_surface_matching -lopencv_tracking -lopencv_datasets -lopencv_text -lopencv_face -lopencv_video -lopencv_ximgproc -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_xobjdetect -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_ml -lopencv_xphoto -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_photo -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core


    $ uname -a
    Linux fedora-23-x64 4.8.13-100.fc23.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Dec 9 14:51:40 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: При конфигурации FFmpeg создаёт файл `config.log`, где можно понять его недовольство. Выложите его для ознакомпления. В FFmpeg 3.2 и 2.8 отличаются условия проверки для OpenCV, есть мнение, что 2.8 не умеет работать с третьей веткой OpenCV, только со второй.

Answer (score 0):

Решилось поднятием версии ffmpeg до 3.2.4